# Is a shorter way of saving in a file and formatting the measured real time when using the `time` bash command

Tags: bash, time, execution-time

I want to use the `time` bash command to measure the execution time of a script, and to save only the real time in a file, with a specific precision. Here is what I have that works:

```
{ time TIMEFORMAT='%4R' <script> 2> <script>.stderr ; } 2>> time.txt
```

But I'm wondering whether there is a shorter way of doing this, or is it possible to use `tee`?

Comment: `tee` is for sending `stdout` to two different destinations, it's not useful for distinguishing the `stderr` of `time` and the command it's executing. Your solution looks pretty good to me.

Comment: If you want something "shorter" for the purpose of interactive use, [unix.se] might be a better place for the question. Stack Overflow is focused on software development, and in a script, being robust and readable is far more important than being terse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is a **shorter** way of saving
>
> I'm wondering whether there is a shorter way of doing this

Yes, just remove the spaces and unneeded quotes. Also, as subshell is most probably not a problem, you can change `{` for `(` to save needed space after `{` and after `}`.

```
(TIMEFORMAT=%4R time cmd 2>cmd.stderr)2>>time.txt
```

It is, if I'm counting right, 8 characters shorter.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thanks also for correcting my  solution, as the `TIMEFORMAT` needs definitely to go first.